# How to populate data on datatables based on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have ajax callback already and it based on the clicked button and will pass username then return it like this

[image]

and this is my AJAX

```
$(document).on("click", ".view", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nomination_result_id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "json/getNominationVoters",
        data: { nomination_result_id: nomination_result_id }, //PASS DATA 
        success: function(data){ // RECEIVE DATA
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

and it open on my modal, this is the content of body

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="voters" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nominee</th>
                    <th>Vote Count</th>         
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                ....................
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and on my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#voters').DataTable();
</script>
```

I don't know how to populate cause the ajax callback on documentation are for document.ready() only not on click. Please need help.

**Update 1**

My Current Script

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "{{ URL::route('json/getNominationVoters') }}",
    data: { nomination_result_id: nomination_result_id }, //PASS DATA 
    success: function(data){ // RECEIVE DATA
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            append_tr = "<tr>"+
                            "<td>"+value.firstname+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+value.lastname+"</td>"+
                        "</tr>";
            $('#voters > tbody:last-child').append(append_tr);      
        });     
    }
});
```

Result: I've got a "No data.."
[image]

Comment: Read about `.append()` or `.html()`

Comment: is this Model related to `Partial View of MVC` ?

Comment: check my edit guys

Answer (score 0):

HTML Data:

```
<table id="voters" class="table">

</table>
```

your scripts are in a document.ready but since your view is loaded after that the scripts don't affect your partial, Use this to solve the Problem

```
function YourScript(){
   // Your script here
}
```

and then call this function `$('#voters').DataTable();` after you have loaded the partial view

```
$('#voters').html(data);
YourScript();
```

Hopefully this helps.